# Is there a way to reach the multitasking bar on the iPad via a keystroke on the keyboard dock?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

When the iPad is plugged into the keyboard dock, you can reach the home screen by pressing the "square" button in the upper left corner of the dock's keyboard. Is there a keyboard analogue to the double-press that brings up the multitasking bar, or do you have to reach for the physical button?

Comment: I didn't realize the dock keyboard was any different! Looking at (warning: huge image) http://septje.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/img_00211.jpg, I'm very inclined to say no, as purely an educated guess. Unless you can hold the home key for some period of time. But still, I doubt it. Note also that you will have no way to select/swipe in the multitasking bar.

Comment: I don't have the keyboard for my iPad so I'm not sure if this works, but does *⌘+Tab* allow app switching analogous to how it works on OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-hitting the `Home` key (at the `Escape` key place) will bring the multitasking bar much like the `Home` button on your iPad.

Confirmed on my iPad Apple keyboard dock.

Comment: That did it! Thank you, and thank you for experimenting.